# Есть ли уязвимость?

Tags: vue.js, frontend, безопасность

Есть фронт. Выявили вот такое поведение. Кажется, что такое поведение нежелательно. При этом уязвимости я не смог придумать.

**Поведение**

1. Захожу под аккаунтом a@b.c в двух вкладках.
2. В одной из вкладок выхожу из аккаунта и захожу под админом.
3. В оставшейся вкладке (a@b.c) пробую загружать данные и совершать действия, в т.ч. на запись и могу это делать.

Т.е. получается я вышел, но сессия не завершилась.

**Должно быть**
После выхода из аккаунта возможности осуществлять навигацию и делать действия быть не должно.

**Как это работает под капотом**:

#### 1. Входим под аккакнтом 1 (А1) в первой вкладке

#### 2. Дублируем вкладку, во второй вкладке видим юзера А1. На данном этапе:

1. В `localStorage` (он общий для всех вкладок в рамках одного origin) сохранён токен А1
2. В каждой вкладке уже запущено Vue-приложение и во внутренней js-переменной установлен токен А1 для всех запросов к серверу

#### 3. Во второй вкладке выходим из аккаунта А1 и входим в другой аккаунт А2. На данном этапе:

2. В `localStorage` для всех вкладок установлен токен пользователя А2
3. В первой вкладке страница не обновлялась и по-прежнему внутри Vue установлен токен по умолчанию для юзера А1
4. Во второй вкладке происходило обновление страницы и внутри Vue токен по умолчанию изменён на А2
5. На данном этапе в первой вкладке действия выполняются под юзером А1, во второй - под А2

#### 4. В первой вкладке обновляем страницу. На данном этапе:

1. В первой вкладке заново загружается Vue-приложение. Оно видит, что в `localStorage` сохранён токен А2 (п 3.1)
2. Приложение берёт этот токен и ставит его в свою внутреннюю переменную по умолчанию для всех запросов
3. Теперь все действия выполняются от имени пользователя А2
4. Во второй вкладке все по-прежнему и действия выполняются тоже от имени пользователя А2

**Вопрос существует ли в таком подходе уязвимость?**

Comment: Вообще нет, но есть событие onstorage, по нему можно смотреть, когда менятеся токен и просто рефрешить страницу. Ну и, если токен связан с какой-то сессией на сервере, то при логауте хорошо бы слать запрос на её закрытие.

Comment: по вашему описанию не видно, где есть возможность совершать действия от разных пользователей в разных вкладках. Но в общем случае, если вы вошли в какой то вкладке под каким либо пользователем, то совершать действия от имени пользователя, который был до этого залогинен в другой вкладке вы не можете.